# Add a custom tab on SpringBoot Admin Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I'm fairly new to Spring. I am trying to integrate custom information from a service into Spring Boot Admin server dashboard.

Out of the box, the Spring boot admin server dashboard for a microservice contains tabs for `Details`, `Metrics`..etc. I need to add one or more custom tabs. I have one of my services serve a dummy endpoint (which would in future serve the custom tab) which I created by following [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators) article. This endpoint extends the `actuator.Endpoint` class.

I have looked into [Spring Boot Admin' Github](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin), at both the Server and the UI but was unable to find a way to integrate a custom endpoint.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "Unable to integrate the custom endpoint"?  What do you mean by that?  Did you get any kind of errors or any kind of message?  What did the UI look like?

Comment: Maybe I should have chose the words correctly but what I meant was... "but was unable to find a way to integrate the custom endpoint."

Comment: An Example of Adding custom tab : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462345/1131967

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no documentation on that. but it is possbible. Look at the [spring-boot-admin-server-ui-activiti](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-server-ui-activiti) module. It adds a tab for a new endpoint.

Comment: I am using SBA 2.0.1, is there any capability to add custom endpoint tab in SBA ? If yes, can you please suggest some reference as an working example type, so that we can refer it and proceed.

Comment: @joshiste the above link does not seem to work, also http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.1.1/#customizing-custom-views-instance does not seem to do justice. It would be great if there a was an example where the custom ui changes and the spring boot admin server are in a single project

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @joshiste:

You can create a custom plugin by making sure your resources are added in the correct directories.

The admin project looks for the following directories:

```
registry.addResourceHandler(adminServerProperties.getContextPath() + "/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/spring-boot-admin-server-ui/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PreferMinifiedFilteringResourceResolver(".min"));

    registry.addResourceHandler(adminServerProperties.getContextPath() + "/all-modules.css")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new ResourcePatternResolvingResourceResolver(resourcePatternResolver,
                    "classpath*:/META-INF/spring-boot-admin-server-ui/*/module.css"))
            .addResolver(new ConcatenatingResourceResolver("\n".getBytes()));

    registry.addResourceHandler(adminServerProperties.getContextPath() + "/all-modules.js")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new ResourcePatternResolvingResourceResolver(resourcePatternResolver,
                    "classpath*:/META-INF/spring-boot-admin-server-ui/*/module.js"))
            .addResolver(new PreferMinifiedFilteringResourceResolver(".min"))
            .addResolver(new ConcatenatingResourceResolver(";\n".getBytes()));
```

So make sure your js / css resources are added in /META-INF/spring-boot-admin-server-ui/etc. and have the correct names: module.js and module.css

**UPDATE** it looks like, it's not possible to add an extra tab to inject your custom plugin into. At least not i.c.w. Angular, like the default plugin. This is mainly due to the fact that all modules and js dependencies of SBA are minified in the build process, but the custom one isn't so you'll get JS errors like:

```
require isn't defined
```

On the following line of the custom module.js:

```
var angular = require('angular');
```

So the only way I see for now, is forking the entire SBA project and copy one of the default plugins as starting point of your own (eg. applications-metrics)