# Spring boot admin add custom tab

Tags: user-interface, spring-boot-admin

I am looking to add a custom tab to spring boot admin server following the documentation at http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.1.1/#customizing-custom-views-instance

However the documentation and the sample project https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/2.1.1/spring-boot-admin-samples/spring-boot-admin-sample-custom-ui do not seem to help understand how to go about it.

My understanding from reading the documentation and the example is that the ui is a separate module.

The pieces I seem to be missing are how do I bundle them ui module and spring boot admin server and serve them.

This is what I have tried thus far: https://github.com/anandsunderraman/custom-spring-boot-admin/tree/master

Answer (score 10):

Did a successfull try to add custom tab in Spring Boot Admin Server.

Pre Requisites :

- Must have npm/node installed and added to $PATH
- Node version must be > 8.0.0.
- If not then download the latest Node from [NodeSite](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- Spring boot Admin version 2.1.1
- A admin/client in working condiition.

Followed these steps(Generate-build the custom UI/Integrate Custom UI in server/Implement Endpoint at client side) :

**Generate/build the custom UI:**

1. Checked out the [spring-boot-admin-custom-sample-ui](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-samples/spring-boot-admin-sample-custom-ui) locally. I am taking sample one as an example
2. `cd <spring-boot-admin-custom-sample-ui-directory>`
3. Run the command `npm install`

   - Above command will install all package. You may get few warnings(for peer dependencies) so try to resolve them as well via installing(`npm install package-name@version-number`) peer dependencies manually. These are npm package depdencies.
4. Import the project in Intellij and Run the maven install command.

   - This will execute `exec-maven-plugin` and a target/dist directory would be created. If any error comes then try to resolve that. I was getting few errors like Node Version issue/vue-template-compiler not found.
   - In case of vue-template-compiler not found error comes then execute `npm install vue-template-compiler@2.5.16`
   - Once maven install completes the it should be done with generating the UI required for new custom tab. Now this needs to integrated in Admin Server. Maven install will install `spring-boot-admin-sample-custom-ui` on local repo as well.

**Integrate custome UI in Admin Server**

5. Just add new properties in application.properties(In order to inject new UI):

   spring.boot.admin.ui.cache.no-cache=true

   spring.boot.admin.ui.extension-resource-locations=file:spring-boot-admin-sample-custom-ui-directory-path/target/dist/

   spring.boot.admin.ui.cache-templates=false
6. Add the dependency for `spring-boot-admin-sample-custom-ui` in server pom.xml. This was built on step 4.
7. Start the Admin Server.

**Implement Endpoint at client Side :**

8. Add the below endpoint :

   @Endpoint(id = "custom")
   public class CustomEndpoint {
       @ReadOperation
       public String getHello(){
           return "Hello" ;
       }
   }

   @Bean
   public CustomEndpoint customEndpoint()
   {
       return new CustomEndpoint();
   }
9. Start the client. You should see something like below on Server :
   [image: Newly Added Custom Tab]

This was all about a sample end point. You can write your own View and follow the similar steps. The views must be implemented as Vue.js components.

Hope this will ease down the process to add new custom tab in spring boot admin.