# Customise default UI of Spring Boot Admin Server

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I want to customize the default page of spring boot admin, and manipulate it ( for eg. Change the order in the list of applications / group some of them as one component, etc. ).

Is it possible to do that, and if yes, what files needed to be changed and which functions need to be overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the above question. The only way we can add customised UI/ Endpoint in SBA ( Spring Boot Admin ) is by developing a custom jar using the sample dependency code and adding it to your server project.

The detailed steps are described in the question: [Spring boot admin add custom tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53418992).